# How to run a Shiny app on ending a Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

It is possible to execute some R code on ending the session of a Shiny app with the help of `session$onSessionEnded`. However, there's an issue if we use that to execute some code which runs a Shiny app. Here is an example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

myGadget <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      session$onSessionEnded(function() {
        myGadget()
      })
      stopApp()
    })
    observeEvent(input$cancel, {
      stopApp()
    })
  }

  runGadget(ui, server, stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}
```

Run `myGadget()` and click on the 'Done' button in the app. Then the gadget stops and it is launched again, but then the RStudio console is not locked as it should be, and there's no button to stop the app.

A solution for an app running in RStudio is to use `rstudioapi::sendToConsole` to send the code to the RStudio console. But not everybody uses RStudio, so I'm looking for a cross-IDE solution.

Comment: from me it works as expected

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Thanks. What is your version of RStudio please? And the one of R?

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour. Is there any specific reason why you use `stopApp` and relaunch the app on session level? Can't you keep the app alive and use `session$close()` instead (for the cancel part)?

Comment: @ismirsehregal Thanks. Yes there's a reason. This is for the "folder gadget" in my package [jsTreeR](https://github.com/stla/jsTreeR). This gadget allows to explore a folder. And when you right-click on a subfolder, you can choose "Explore here" in the context menu. This relaunches the gadget with this subfolder as the root folder.

Comment: Ah you said a reason for using `stopApp`? I will try `session$close()` instead.

Comment: That does not work with `session$close()`.

Comment: exactly - I was asking for the reason to use `stopApp`. I guess you are already aware of it but `onStop` also gives you the possibility to run a function after the application is stopped which might be of interest.

Comment: Have you thought about wrapping your "folder gadget" in a module so you can call it several times (without using `stopApp`)? Here is a related [article](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/shiny-add-removing-modules-dynamically/).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm using `R version 3.6.1` without `Rstudio`

Comment: the problem occurs only in `Rstudio`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Nice, thank you. So I can use `rstudioapi::sendToConsole` for RStudio users.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent did you ever find out how to do this correctly in a way that doesn't rely on rstudioapi?

Comment: @DeanAttali No, never found a non-rstudio way.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I left an appoach below. Not pretty but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround using a while loop to wrap the app object:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

canceled <- FALSE
myGadget <- function() {
  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp()
    })
    observeEvent(input$cancel, {
      canceled <<- TRUE
      stopApp()
    })
  }
  runGadget(ui, server, stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}

while (!canceled) {
  myGadget()
}
```

---

**1. Edit:** As an alternative (to avoid `<<-`) we can use a global `reactiveVal`:

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

canceled <- reactiveVal(FALSE)

ui <- miniPage(
  gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$done, {
    stopApp()
  })
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    canceled(TRUE)
    stopApp()
  })
}

myGadget <- shinyApp(ui, server)

while (isolate(!canceled())) {
  runGadget(myGadget, stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}
```

---

**2. Edit:** Another alternative to avoid `<<-`: Using `stopApp()`'s return value as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567757/chaining-shiny-gadgets-how-to-run-a-shiny-gadget-based-on-return-value-of-anoth):

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

ui <- miniPage(
  gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$done, {
    stopApp(FALSE)
  })
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    stopApp(TRUE) # set myGadget return value
  })
}

myGadget <- shinyApp(ui, server)

canceled <- FALSE
while (!canceled) {
  canceled <- runGadget(myGadget, stopOnCancel = FALSE)
}
```

---

**3. Edit:** Another option is to keep the app alive (instead of restarting it) using `session$reload()` instead of `stopApp()`

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

ui <- miniPage(
  gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$done, {
    session$reload()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$cancel, {
    stopApp()
  })
}

myGadget <- shinyApp(ui, server)

runGadget(myGadget, stopOnCancel = FALSE)
```