# Chaining Shiny gadgets: How to run a Shiny gadget based on return value of another Shiny gadget

Tags: r, shiny

Suppose I have a Shiny gadget that returns a value. Based on that value, I may want to run another Shiny gadget. Here is some example code:

```r
library(shiny)

app1 <- shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    "app1",
    checkboxInput("launch", "launch app2"),
    actionButton("done", "done")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp(input$launch)
    })
  }
)

app2 <- shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    "app2",
    checkboxInput("launch", "launch app1"),
    actionButton("done", "done")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      stopApp(input$launch)
    })
  }
)

run_app1 <- function() {
  ret <- runGadget(app1, viewer = dialogViewer("app1"))
  if (ret) run_app2()
}

run_app2 <- function() {
  ret <- runGadget(app2, viewer = dialogViewer("app2"))
  if (ret) run_app1()
}
```

If you run `run_app1()` and check the box, I want app2 to run after closing. When app2 runs, if the box is checked, then app1 will run after closing. This code does now work.

I can solve it by using `rstudioapi::sendToConsole("run_app2()")` instead of `run_app2()`, but I want a solution that isn't specific to RStudio. Does anyone know how to solve this?

**I don't want to place this logic inside the gadget itself, it needs to go outside of the gadget**

(This is a xpost from [RStudio Community Forums](https://community.rstudio.com/t/160825), if there is an answer there, I'll update this post)

Comment: This seems to work fine when using `paneViewer` or `browserViewer` instead of `dialogViewer`. For future readers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64242967/9841389) you can find a related question.

Comment: Ok - I just saw you already filed an issue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/12760).

Comment: @ismirsehregal yes I did, I'm still keeping this question open to see if anyone has ever successfully done this